# Video background not displaying properly on some computer

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am meeting an error on my website and I can't put my finger on it, the custom video background I'm trying to implement works on some computers and doesn't on the some other.

It is not a problem of browser version since I tried it on 5 computers with the same versions and there is still 2 computer who fail to run the javascript on this specific area (it either works on all browser or the javascript goes off on all plateforms).

I think it is a problem of computer but what should I in order to make the JS of the video background work ? (If you can't pause or play the video, or if it launch as soon as you enter the page then you also have this issue)

Here is the website : [www.fyz.ch/VR](http://www.fyz.ch/VR)

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: @j08691 Alright ! I'll reread the docs, won't happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to convert the video in multiple file formats (mp4, webm and ogv).

I think you made a wrong structure for it and put a `source` tag outside of the `video` tag.

Add them like this :

```
<video>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogg" />

    Your browser doesn't support the video tag
</video>
```

Moreover, it seems like you added the `autoplay` attribute to the `video` tag. So it's the normal behavior for the video to launch itself as soon as the user enters the site.

Could you provide some code to be sure of what your problem is ?